# How to get list of checked checkboxes in django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

Here, 'arr' is a list passed from a previous view. The values(string type) of this list along with the check boxes are successfully being displayed.

```
<form action="{% url 'prec' %}" method="post">
{% for link in arr %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="{{link}}" />{{link}}<br>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In views function, I create a list of the fields/boxes checked by the user.
(views.py):

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def prec(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        var = request.POST.getlist('checks[]')
        return render(request, 'Link5_prec.html', {'variables':var})
```

Then, in another template, I want to display the values checked by the user(along with the index of that checkbox like [0,2,3]). But nothing is being displayed. 
(Link5_prec.html):

```
{% for v in variables %}
    <h1>{{v}}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Also, if possible, in the first template, I want to make a checkbox of all the elements in the 'arr' list except the last element.